# Why does $\sum_{J\subset I\subset S/F}(-1)^{|I|}=0$? (Alvis-Curtis Duality)

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $S$ is the reflection generators of the Coxeter group of some reductive algebraic group $G$. Let $F$ denote the Frobenius automorphism. The Alvis-Curtis duality $D_G$ is known to an involution on virtual characters, and part of the proof boils down to

> $\sum_{J\subset I\subset S/F}(-1)^{|I|}=0$ whenever $J\neq S/F$, since it's the expansion of $(1-1)^n$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the complement of $J$ in $S/F$.

How does one deduce this combinatorial interpretation?

Comment: Most of your tags are irrelevant. This is purely combinatorics, and it more or less comes down to an application of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My mistake, and thanks. Someone told me to add more tags to garner more attention. I've removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any finite sets $A,B$, any set $S$ with $A \subseteq S \subseteq B$ can be written as $A \cup T$ where $T$ is an arbitary subset of $B \backslash A$.  Letting $n = |B \backslash A|$, we get

$$\sum_{A \subseteq S \subseteq B} (-1)^{|S|} = \sum_{T \subseteq B \backslash A} (-1)^{|T| + |A|} =   (-1)^{|A|}\sum_k \sum_{T \subseteq B \backslash A, |T| = k} (-1)^{k}  = (-1)^{|A|}\sum_k {n \choose k} (-1)^k = (-1)^{|A|}(1+-1)^n = 0$$ if $n > 0$.